# EditText created dynamically : getText() doesn't return a value

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to get the value of an editText and store it on shared preferences, I did this :

```
SharedPreferences participant;
    Editor editor;
    private EditText firstname = null;
    private String name =null;
    private LinearLayout formbis;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_participant);

        participant = this.getSharedPreferences("participant", getBaseContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = participant.edit();


        formbis = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.formbis);



        firstname = new EditText(this);
        firstname.setHint("first name");
        firstname.setTextSize(12);
        firstname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        name = firstname.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("key", name);
        editor.commit();

        formbis.addView(firstname);
```

But when I open the sharedPreferences XML file i only find this : no value from the editText :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="key"></string>
</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a listener to your `EditText` and then commit the value when the user enters some text.

Answer (score 2):

`getText` returns the result of a previous `setText`.  Call `firstname.setText("your string")` .

In the snippet you provide the user has not time to enter text. When you call the commit is to late. You can, for instance, have a "confirm button" and when you click upon it, in its `onClick` call commit on your edittext, or you can implements [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
private class MyTextWather implements TextWatcher {


    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
         // it is called every time you put something inside your edittext

}
```

Comment: so what should I do to return the value of a text entered by a user ?

Comment: in the snippet you provide the user has not time to enter text. When you call the commit is to late. You can, for instance, have a "confirm  button" and when you click upon it, in its onClick call commit on your edittext, or you can implements TextWatcher

Comment: Can you give me more explanations please (I'm a beginner ) , should I use some kind of listener ?

Comment: You would want to move `name = firstname.getText().toString();` to some listener such as an `onClick()`, `TextWatcher` or something similar